# How to add certbot to another port

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, certbot

I'm setting up the backend of my server but I can't get certbot to work on my API using https. Only my website is being redirect to https.

I'm just not that fluent with nginx, I don't know how I can fix this issue. I need the last server to use certbot, on port 4444.

```
root /var/www/domain.com/public;

server {

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com blog.domain.com;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $Host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
               # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = blog.domain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name domain.com blog.domain.com www.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4444;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $Host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
               # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need some clarification on this line here:

> I need the last server to use certbot, on port 4444

Did you mean to say accessing port 4444 (via reverse proxy) with a certificate issued by Certbot?

In the last server block, you might have missed setting the `server_name`. Notice that you had this line in your previous server blocks.

Assuming the following scenarios:

#### API is running in a different subdomain

- API: api.domain.com (Where your API is running)
- certificate by Certbot issued a wildcard certificate in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com`

Given these assumptions, the suggested server block configuration can be like:

```
server {
    server_name api.domain.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

     location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4444;
        ## additional proxy configurations here
    }
}
```

If you haven't requested for the wildcard certificate to cover all subdomains, I suggest requesting specifically for your API subdomain, and modify `ssl_certificate_key` and `ssl_certificate` paths as necessary.

#### API is part of primary domain

- API: domain.com/api (API is running inside domain.com)

If this is the case, consider adding a location block insider your first server block:

```
server {
    ....
    location / {
        ..... no changes here
    }

    ## add this block
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4444;
        ## additional proxy configurations here
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    ....
}
```

In this scenario, no changes needed for `ssl_certificate_key` and `ssl_certificate` paths.

Hope that helps!